# Error in execCallbacks after closing shiny app in rstudio desktop

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I run shiny app on Rstudio desktop and then close it I get the error below. Any help on what it means?

```
Error in execCallbacks(timeoutSecs, all, loop$id) : 
  invoke_wrapped: throwing std::runtime_error
```